# How to enable AdSupport framework to Xamarin.ios project

Tags: xamarin.ios, firebase-analytics

In order to enable some Analytics features in google firebase analytics. I have to enable AdSupport Framework. It is pretty clear how to do it in native Xcode project following this steps https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/analytics-adsupport

I am having trouble with enable it in Xamarin.ios project. I did some research and some says need a binding project to wrap the .framework file and link this project. here: [How to use ios framework in xamarin.ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376743/how-to-use-ios-framework-in-xamarin-ios), but I think only firebase framework will use the AdSupport framework. Thus Do I need to do the binding?

I would be very appreciated if someone can point out a way! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AdSupport has been included in Xamarin.iOS. only use code

```
using AdSupport;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick respond! Well, does that mean I don't need to do anything to enable "some Analytics features" in google firebase analytics, because it's been included in the Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: I haven't got a change to test it. Definite will get back to you when I did. Thanks!

Comment: Hey mate, I still cannot see  user properties like Age and Interests. Is it only work after publish on the Apple store, not work for internal release? Or just the sample group (users) is too small.

Comment: Hi @Lucas, is there a way to exclude AdSupport class as I don't want my Firebase Analytics SDK to use it? If the AdSupport is included in the app, Firebase says it will pick it up to access the IDFA. This is for the new privacy requirements in iOS 14 from Apple

Comment: I saw a way to exclude assemblies in Xamarin.ios Linker, but is it possible to exclude this AdSupport class of an assembly in Linker?

Comment: How to exclude AdSupport from Xamarin.iOS, so we avoid apple rejection due to new App Tracking Transparency framework on iOS 14.5?